# Need help in extracting unique lines from a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file with the below details:

```
**169.254.230.157 : 169.254.42.146**
169.254.230.157 : 169.254.138.97
169.254.230.157 : 169.254.162.67
169.254.223.76 : 169.254.42.146
**169.254.223.76 : 169.254.138.97**
169.254.223.76 : 169.254.162.67
```

I need to get the unique lines like the below

```
169.254.230.157 : 169.254.42.146
169.254.223.76 : 169.254.138.97
```

Below is what i was trying:

```
    ping_ip = open("ping.txt","r")
    ping_lines = ping_ip.readlines()

    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for line in ping_lines:
        ip_s, ip_d = line.split(":")
        #print ip_s, " : ", ip_d
        m = re.search(ip_s.rstrip(),line)
        n = re.search(ip_d.rstrip(),line)
        if m and n not in list1 and list2 :
            list1.append(m.group(0))
            list2.append(n.group(0))
            print line
    print set(list1)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `if m and n not in list1 and list2 :` This doesn't work like you expect it to.  This is like saying `if (m) and (n not in list1) and (list2) :`

Comment: Aren't all lines unique? I don't see any repeated line in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for unique combinations (i.e. neither item has been added already). You should be clearer on your definition of unique:

```
r = []
with open(...) as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        x = line.strip().split(' : ')
        if all(i not in seen for i in x):
            r.append(line.strip())
            seen |= set(x)
r
```

Output:

```
['169.254.230.157 : 169.254.42.146', '169.254.223.76 : 169.254.138.97']
```

Comment: In the example provided in the question, all combinations of `IP1 : IP2` are unique, so it's not clear what "unique" means in this case

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I agree, but as you can see using the definition of unique above gives the desired output.

Comment: Yeah, seems from the original code like maybe OP wants "each line in which neither IP address has appeared in any of the preceding lines." But without clarification from OP, I'd prefer not to see an answer make that assumption.

Comment: @smarx A little more subtle than that, neither IP address has been added to the result. `169.254.138.97` had already been seen but not included.

Comment: Good point. That's such a bizarre thing that I think it's unlikely to be what OP actually wants. I believe we should continue to wait for clarification (though I've already voted to close as well, since the question has been open in this ambiguous state for quite a while).

Comment: Firstly i apologize for not being clear on my question.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but if you are trying to get the unique values from a list of values such as the IP addresses you listed, you can put your data into a Set, which by definition is a collection of unique items.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html](http://Read%20About%20Python%20Sets)

With your code, you could do something like this(not sure this works but just for demonstration purposes):

```
from sets import Set
### - print IPs - ###
ping_ip = open("ping.txt","r")
ping_lines = ping_ip.readlines()

count = 0
print "################################################"
print "START"
print "################################################"
try:
#####
set1=Set()
set2=Set()
for line in ping_lines:
    ip_s, ip_d = line.split(":")
    set1.add(ip_s)
    set2.add(ip_d)
    print set(list1)
    print set(list2)
    #####
except:
    print "exiting..."
```